# Getting Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Tags: testng

my project is on e drive D:\EclipseWorkSpace\F12 Network this is path and here i stored bin and libs,
this is my classpath is set classpath=D:\EclipseWorkSpace\F12 Network\bin;D:\EclipseWorkSpace\F12 Network*;

this is batch file code java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG "C:\EclipseWorkSpace\F12 Network\testng.xml"

tried many other things also

Comment: Can you include your code that is related to the error?

Comment: its happened because of some jar overwrite or more than one is in lib folder.

Comment: Thanks lima i resolve it i tried to add new all jar in to libs folder and remove all existing ones.